# Elasticsearch Exact Match using Elasticsearch client in net7

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, .net-7.0, elasticsearch-client

I have a NET7 project that use Elasticsearch official client at version 8.11. In this project I try to do an exact match in my product's list, searching a product by slug.

I read here and on the official documentation (only up to version 7 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/match-phrase-usage.html ) that I have to use the MatchPrase method but, when I switch to version 8.x page, I see that resource is removed.

For me slug **firstword-secondword** and slug **firstword** are **different slug** but when I search using my query and I pass "firstword" as parameter I obtain first and second result, because Elasticsearch tokenize my slug removing stopping word "-".

At the moment I tried with this queries:

```
var result = await Client.SearchAsync<Category>(
index => index.Index(idsIndex).Query(q => q.MatchPhrase(m => m.Field(f => f.Id).Query(slug))),
    cancellationToken);


var result = await Client.SearchAsync<Category>(
index => index.Index(idsIndex).Query(q => q.Term(m => m.Field(x => x.Id).Value(slug))),
     cancellationToken);

 var result = await Client.SearchAsync<Brand>(
 index => index.Index(idsIndex).Query(q => q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Id).Query(slug))),
 cancellationToken);
```

return result.Documents.FirstOrDefault();

obtaining same results.
Someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: *"because Elasticsearch tokenize my slug removing stopping word"* - sounds like index problem, you better dig elasticsearch mappings and see if the slug field is of a [`keyword` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) and dont forget to reindex the whole thing. common mistake in elasticsearch first timer is to just shove json in and be done with it expecting it to magically work..